# VAADIN page navigaion and validation

Tags: vaadin

In VAADIN, i tried many options for page navigation. Only Link component option is working. Creating new windows all the times won't be useful for building a large enterprise application. The problem with link component is when the user gives that link directly in the browser the page is coming. Is there any option for filtering the pages using filters and any xml's for checking and forwarding to correct page like struts-config or faces-config.xml?
Is there any option for cookie hanling, tampering and maintaining session between different tabs and windows?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Navigator7 addon for navigation? [link to navigator7 addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/navigator7)

You can create pages using @Page annotation and place components on it and navigate using page names and ids.